# CSS Grid breakline

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to implement a CSS grid template which should behave as follows:

In desktop, it should look like this

[image: Desktop]

For tablet,

[image: Tablet]

and mobile

[image: Mobile]

I implemented using Grid and template areas but I have a problem with tablet. Requirement is, if content in B doesn't fit in, let's say, 50% of the space, then, there should be a *break line* so B will take 100% of space and C would be pushed to the 3rd row (just as in mobile)

I'm not sure if this is possible with grid. I tried using `auto-fit` and `auto-fill` properties but not getting anywhere.

Hope you can help me

Comment: use `media queries` and use different `grid-template-areas` definition?

Comment: I used media queries for tablets and mobiles, but, the problem is, it doesn't depend on the resolution, it depends on the content.

Answer (score 2):

CSS grid + media queries can do the job:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.a {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
}

.b {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
}

.c {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .a {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
  }

  .c {
    grid-row-start: 2;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 300px;
  }

  .a {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
  }

  .c {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
</div>
```